# Iphone Mail not displaying message correctly from PHP

Tags: php, html, iphone

I have a website contact form that sends HTML email with photo attachments as an email to Iphone mail application. I am receiving the following error message on my Iphone:

"This message cannot be displayed because of the way it is formatted. Ask the sender to send it again using a different format or email program. multipart/mixed".

Anyone can please help?

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = 
$boundary\r\n\r\n";
$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body));
$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the body content type:

```
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html;"
```

Comment: now only image is showing when I used your code no body text anymore. Any other suggestions?